# How to read the blob data from servlet request object

Tags: java

There is client and server components, the client is sending the data in more secure way by converting the data in blob using POST method to the server.

Can any suggest me how to convert that blob data to string object in server side(Java).i have tried some code below

```
         Way 1):
        ==============================
        String streamLength = request.getHeader("Content-Length");
        int streamIntLength = Integer.parseInt(streamLength);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[streamIntLength];
        request.getInputStream().read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        String content = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(bytes);
        System.out.println(content);

        Output for above code is  : some junk data is displaying.

        dABlAG0AcABsAGEAdABlAD0AMgAzADUAUgBfAFAAcgBvAHYAaQBkAGUAcgBfA

        Way 2) : 
        ======
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        request.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
           String str = new String(line.getBytes());
           System.out.println(str);
        }

        Please suggest me any one, above both ways are not worked out.
```

Comment: Possibly its url-safe encoded data, you need to decode it, the same way as it was encoded by the client

Comment: I have tried some code to decode but it doesn't worked for me:String streamLength = request.getHeader("Content-Length");
      int streamIntLength = Integer.parseInt(streamLength);
      byte[] bytes = new byte[streamIntLength];
         request.getInputStream().read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
         byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(bytes);
      System.out.println("decodedBytes " + new String(decodedBytes));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code works for me.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
try {
String streamLength = request.getHeader("Content-Length");
int streamIntLength = Integer.parseInt(streamLength);
InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
if (inputStream != null) {
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
inputStream));
char[] charBuffer = new char[streamIntLength];
int bytesRead = -1;
while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
} else {
stringBuilder.append("");
}
} catch (IOException ex) {
throw ex;
} 
String body = stringBuilder.toString();
//System.out.println(body);
byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
System.out.println(StringUtils.newStringUtf16Le(bytes));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the first approach, it looks like the data is encoded (possibly in Base64 format). After decoding it, what is the problem you are facing ? If the data is String and then encoded to Base64, you should get the actual string after decoding it. (Assuming platform locales on client and server side are same).

If its a binary data, better you keep it inside a byte stream only. If you anyhow want it to convert to a string, then the first approach looks okay.
If this binary data represents some kind of file, you can get the related information using the HTTP headers and write it to temp location for further use.